# How to get some cell in last row of datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows, cells

i have table like below
[image]

these are the code that i'm trying to do, no hope though, i want to get that `CAid014` value

```
string splitter = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount].Cells[0].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(splitter); // to print what splitter got
```

---

i'm using datagridview1.rowcount so the datagridview1.rows will get the last rows. and cells[0] will get the 0 index of row and it got error.

how do i get that `CAid` cells ?

---

solved : i miss that value like this

```
 string splitter = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount].Cells[0].value.ToString();
```

Comment: Did you tried `dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1]` ??

Comment: @yogi yeah i did that, the mbox didn't show CAid014

Comment: @Anonymous i want to get the CAid014. is it correct if i use cells[0] ?

Comment: @nencor:- See if you use Rows it will return Row Collection and thus adding [X] will point the X th index in the collection.So cells[0] obiviously returns the content of first cell in the last row.So its better to use String.Format("{0}",dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount-1].Cells[0].Value).Perhaps there is value2 property as well I barely remember ;you can try

Comment: @nencor you should accept one answer if we help you

Comment: @anonymous can we use value such `dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount].Cells[0].Value.ToString()` for easier method to get cells ?

Comment: @elvieejo did i break any rule if i accept more than one answer ? sorry, i just appreciate the support that you guys given to me :)

Comment: @nencor:- I already gave an answer to do it in an easy way, you can try and let me know if its any good to you :)

Answer (score 5):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

`.Rows` is a collection, and also works like an array,  and the index numeration of `arrays` goes from 0 to `N-1`

Comment: it returned "DatagridviewTextboxcell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=3 }"

i want to get the CAid014, how do i get that ?

Comment: @nencor use `Cells[0].value` .

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do it, is :-

```
string splitter = (String)dataGridView1[ 0,dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Value;

MessageBox.Show(splitter);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Row Collection` in the `datagridview` are 0 based index. so I agree with `dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[0].ToString();`

Comment: you need to use value to return the value of the cells